# Is this a good practice to connect to a database connection file outside rood dir?

Tags: php, mysql

Is this a good practice for the connection file located outside rood dir? I feel that there is something better than using all these dots and slashes, though it is working properly!
Note: dbc folder is outside the root by one level as the following:
dbc/public_html/crud/data_entry/process/insert.php

```
<?php //file name insert.php

include '../../../../dbc/connect_db.php';

....

?>
```

Comment: php path should be relative and not absolute. your code should never run see if this helps https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths

Comment: @nbk it is working properly, by the way I am on localhost.

Comment: like i said path should be relitive to the the wenbserver, but as both point to the same file it doesn't matter